# Paging is not working in my kendo ui grid in angular js

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to implement server side paging,sorting and filtering in kendo grid ui with script in angular js but problem is paging is not working.

First 10 records are displaying but when i click on page no 2 then server side call is not going and no records are displayed.

Source:http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

This is my View:

```
 <link href="~/css/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="GridDemoCtrl">
                <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
                </kendo-grid>
            </div>
   <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="~/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/kendo.all.min.js.js"></script>
```

My Script:

```
app.controller('GridDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "../Holiday/GetListofHolidays",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
         {
             field: "HolidayName",
             title: "Holiday Name"
         },
         {
             field: "HolidayDiscription",
             title: "Holiday Description"
         }
        ]
    };
}]);
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetListofHolidays(DataSourceRequest command)
        {
           var holidayList = _holidayService.GetAllHolidays(command.Page - 1, command.PageSize,null);
           var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
           {
               Data = holidayList.Select(x =>
               {
                   var holidayModel = new HolidayModel();
                   holidayModel.HolidayName = x.HolidayDiscription;
                   holidayModel.HolidayDate = x.HolidayDate;
                   holidayModel.HolidayDiscription = x.HolidayDiscription;
                   return holidayModel;
               }),
               Total = holidayList.TotalCount,
           };
           return Json(gridModel);
        }

public  class DataSourceRequest
    {
        public int Page { get; set; }

        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        public DataSourceRequest()
        {
            this.Page = 1;
            this.PageSize = 10;
        }
    }

public class DataSourceResult
    {
        public object ExtraData { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable Data { get; set; }

        public object Errors { get; set; }

        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
```

So please anybody can guide me whats the problem with my code and why paging is not working???

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Kendo handle the paging, etc. Ensure the LINQ (are you using an ORM like Entity Framework?) in your query does not execute the query yet and have `GetAllHolidays()` return an IQueryable. `holidayList.ToDataSourceResult()` will add the paging, sorting and filtering and execute the query.

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetListofHolidays([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<HolidayModel> holidayList = _holidayService.GetAllHolidays();
    return Json(holidayList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: i am doing this with script.Please see my question and my DataSourceRequest is a custom class created by me and yes i am using entity framework